# Markov processes associated with generators being differential operators of higher order $n>2$

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $P$ be a $C_0$-semigroup on the space of all bounded Borel functions on $\Bbb R^n$ with $P_t1= 1$ for all $t$. It corresponds to a continuous time Markov process $X$ such that $\mathbb E(f(X_t)|X_0 = x) = P_tf(x)$. A generator of $P$ is given by
$$
Af(x):=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{P_tf(x) - f(x)}t.
$$
From what I know

- if $A$ is a first order differential operator, $X$ is a solution of an ODE
- if $A$ is a second order differential operator, $X$ is an Ito diffusion
- if $A$ has an integral term, $X$ has jumps.

Yet, I have never saw an example of what happens when $A$ is a differential operator of an order higher than $2$. Which kind of stochastic process will that correspond to? I'd be happy to see an example for $A = \frac{d^3}{d^3x}$ and $A = \frac{d^4}{d^4x}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ is the infinitesimal generator of a process $X_t$. Then, $$
Af(x) = \lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{P_tf(x) - f(x)}{t} = \frac{\mathbb E[f(X_t)|X_0=x]-f(x)}{t} \quad \text{for all } x \in \mathbb R^d,f\in D(A), 
$$
where $D(A)$ is some appropriate Banach space.

In particular, such operators must satisfy what is called the "absolute maximum principle". That is, assume that $f \in D(A)$ and $x_0 \in \mathbb R^d$ are such that $f(x_0) = \sup_{y \in \mathbb R^d} f(y)< \infty$ i.e. $f$ attains its maximum over $\mathbb R^d$, and at the point $x_0$. Then, for all $y \in \mathbb R^d, f(y) \leq f(x_0)$. As a consequence, for all $t >0$, \begin{align}& \mathbb E[f(X_t)|X_0=x_0] \leq \mathbb E[f(x_0)|X_0=x_0] = f(x_0)\\ \implies & \frac{\mathbb E[f(X_t)|X_0=x_0]-f(x_0)}{t}\leq 0 \quad\text{for all } t>0 \\
\implies & Af(x_0)\leq 0. \end{align}

We have proved that whenever $f(x_0) = \max_{y \in \mathbb R^d} f(y)$, then $Af(x_0) \leq 0$. This particular property is referred to as the absolute maximum principle in the literature, and is a *necessary condition* for an operator to be the infinitesimal generator of a Markov process.

---

The operators $\frac{d^3}{dx^3}$ and $\frac{d^4}{dx^4}$ don't satisfy the absolute maximum property.

For example, let $f(x) = -x^4+x^2$. Then, $\max_{y \in \mathbb R^d} f(y) = f(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}})$, but $\frac{d^3f}{dx^3} = -24x$, and hence $\frac{d^3f}{dx^3}(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}})>0$. (Note : $f$ is in the domain of $A$ but if one additionally requires $f \in L^2(m)$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure, which is sometimes a requirement included in the definition of $D(A)$, then one can easily modify $f$ outside the interval $[-2,2]$ to keep it thrice differentiable but also integrable, say. Use bump functions). Hence, one shows that $\frac{d^3}{dx^3}$ doesn't have the absolute maximum property.

Similarly, consider the function $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}, f(0)=0$. This is also known as the $\mbox{sinc}$ function. The function has a global maximum at $x=0$. However, I leave you to check that $\frac{d^4}{dx^4}(\mbox{sinc})(0) = \frac{1}{5}>0$. In particular, this operator also does not satisfy the absolute maximmum property.

---

To the best of my belief, operators of order strictly greater than $2$ should not satisfy the absolute maximum property, and therefore cannot be probabilistically studied using an associated process. This also means that powers of the fractional Laplacian $-(\Delta)^a,a>1$ cannot be studied using the associated process.

Note that an analogous "relative-maximum-principle" is also available, which talks about the analogous condition but $x_0$ is only required to be a local maximum of $f$ rather than a global maximum. Characterizations of operators satisfying both properties, for operators of order at least $2$, may be found in the following (French) paper :

> *Courrege, P.*, [**Sur la forme intégro-différentielle des opérateurs de (C_ k^ \infty) dans (C) satisfaisant au principe du maximum**](https://eudml.org/doc/109338), Semin. Theorie Potentiel M. Brelot, G. Choquet et J. Deny 10 (1965/66), No. 2, 38 p. (1967). [ZBL0155.17402](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0155.17402).\

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Is this condition also related to the fact that $P_t$ must map positive functions to positive ones?

Comment: @SBF If I'm not wrong, $P_t$ as currently written may still map positive functions to positive functions. However, one also requires that $f \leq 1$ then $P_tf \leq 1$ a.e. , the "contractive" condition which is required to make the semigroup Markovian. I think this is the one which is violated for the two operators in question, although it may be possible that the other condition is as well (not fully sure though). What I do know is that given $A$, if one creates the corresponding bilinear form and it is a "regular Dirichlet" form, then a Markov process can be created from it.

Comment: To the best of my French, the first theorem in the quoted paper states that any linear operator on the relevant domain satisfying the absolute maximum principle must be a second order differential operator with a symmetric matrix of second order coefficients. So I guess that may indeed characterize such operators. Strangely though integral term is not mentioned there. Perhaps because of the domain definition.

Comment: @SBF Theorem 0.1 is actually the *relative maximum principle* : if $A$ satisfies the relative maximum principle (in addition, it insists that one only needs to consider $f$ such that $f$'s relative maximum is positive, so the condition is slightly weaker and I don't know if it's necessary) then $A$ is of the form $(0.1)$ where $a_{ij},b_i,c$ are continuous functions, $c(x) \leq 0$ and $a_{ij}(x)$ is a symmetric positive-semidefinite matrix for each $x$.

Comment: Theorem 1.4 of the same paper is a characterization of operators satisfying an "absolute maximum principle". Note that the author provides three such principles (P),(PM),(PML), and the condition PM is what we are looking for, except the author insists that we only need to look at $f$ non-negative.

Comment: Thank you very much. This time you won’t be an unsung hero

Comment: @SBF Glad to be of help!

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer- What about the square of a Markov generator? Can it also be a generator? It does seem possible that it satisfies the maximum principle. Take the square of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, for instance.

Comment: @matilda The square of *some* Markov generators can certainly be Markov, I mean the derivative is a Markov generator (of the "constant" drift process) as is its square, which is the second derivative i.e. one-dimensional Laplacian (the generator of a BM at twice the speed). In general, though : no. For example, take the square of the second derivative, which is the fourth derivative. It doesn't satisfy the maximum principle as I mention above, so it can't be the generator of a Markov process. The OU process "squared" probably refers to the square of the *sample paths* of the OU process.

Comment: But you should not give up, @matilda even if you have an operator that doesn't satisfy the maximum principle, because, if you're willing to lose the Markov property you can still get by. For example, see Funaki's solution to $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac 1{8} \frac{\partial^4 u}{\partial x^4}$ uses the "iterated" Brownian motion, which is (an appropriate version of) roughly of the form $B_{W_t}$ where $W_t,B_t$ are independent Brownian motions (essentially a Brownian motion running by a Brownian clock). This process is *not* Markov but connected to that diff. eqn. anyway.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer- Thank you for your nice references. I am studying the square of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck operator for a particular problem I have in geometry. However, I am now convinced that this squared operator is not a Markov generator because it has positive eigenvalues $k^2$ for all integers $k$, and hence by Hille-Yoshida we can conclude it is not a generator. Is this line of reasoning correct?

Comment: @matilda Yeah, I believe that you're right, although I believe you can derive the infinitesimal generator of such a process and confirm that it doesn't satisfy the maximum principle as well, to show that the process isn't Markov.